# Horizontal scrolling layout manager for recycler view with multiple rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to achieve a horizontally scrollable recyclerview layout manager which I can be able to have multiple rows where the first item can occupy the whole spans:

So if the number of rows is 3 it would be:
[image]

By scrolling:
[image]

Do I need to write my own custom layout manager? or is there any trick to do it? or any available code?

Comment: You can achieve this by using RecyclerView and use GridLayout in place of linear layout for recycler view and use horizontal orientation.

Comment: Not really. Of course, you can have a horizontal grid, but you cannot use the span size lookup in a horizontal grid, hence, the first item cannot be like what in the image